# How to prevent nav items from being stacked vertically on resize?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Whenever the window is resized, the below happens which is what I'm trying to prevent. I want `Item 1` and `Item 2` to stay on the same line.

[image: nav]

Here's what's in the template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

I tried:

```
ul .nav-item {
    display: inline;
}
```

and

```
.nav-item {
    display: inline;
}
```

and

```
.nav-item {
    float: top;
}
```

and

```
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 row">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link col" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link col" aria-current="page" href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: use display:flex; on ul

Comment: not working ...

Comment: If you could post all your code for the page it would make it easier to understand what's going on.

Comment: There's nothing else in the page, just the minimal html tags, head, body, ...